# Was an adobe fort or a palisade fort more defensible?

Tags: military, russia, 18th-century, spanish-empire, castles

All else equal, when these types of forts were in use, was an **adobe** fort or a **palisade** fort more defensible?

A bit of *what-if* led to this question. Russians ostrogs such as Nizhnekamchatsk and Fort Ross had palisade perimeters while Spanish presidios such as Tubac and Santa Barbara had adobe perimeters. The two empires never battled (at least in the Americas) even though their most remote forts fell within about 100km of each other. Sample (not necessarily representative) images follow:

[image: Adobe of a presidio]
[image: Palisade of an ostrog]

Comment: Where? In a forest a palisade is more easily repaired and defended, while in a more arid and sunny environment an adobe fort may be more easily repaired and defended.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is not which is more defensible, but which can be more quickly constructed using available materials and is better suited to the opponents.  Palisade will do better against arrows than cannon, and is generally faster to erect.  I doubt there are many situations where the defending commander has the option to build one or th eother.

Comment: I think you are overlooking a highly significant point here.  The Spanish build adobe forts where there were few trees and not much rain.  The Russians (and Americans) built palisade forts where there were plentiful trees and lots of rain.

Comment: @jamesqf, you're right about the general trends. the proximity of San Francisco and Fort Ross suggests that climate and vegetation were not the only factors at play, though.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast defensible against the strategies and technologies of the era when these forts were being used. thanks.

Comment: Aaron, could you add that to the question?  I think it would help with the clarity bit.

Comment: @Aaron Brick: Of course it's possible that there was a "but we've always built them this way" effect as the Spanish moved north along the coast.  But if you're familiar with California rainfall patterns, you'll know that it's much drier east of the coastal mountains, which I think is where most of the forts were built.

Comment: @jamesqf it's true that the whole north of New Spain was characteristically dry, but the four presidios of Alta California were all coastal. The empire had military engineers to design adobe forts complying with the Reglamento of 1772. It might have been tough to switch to palisade construction when they reached a more forested area.

Comment: @Aaron Brick: I was thinking more of the whole string of mission/forts, pretty much along the line of highway 101.  I wonder if the Monterey & SF forts (and the Santa Cruz mission) had major problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe forts are more defensible. Perhaps the most famous one was the [Alamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alamo_Mission_in_San_Antonio). During the war for Texas independence, it was defended by less than 200 Texans for nearly two weeks against odds of 10-15 to one.

A [palisade fort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palisade) was mainly a stopgap against relatively small bands of soldiers. It was vulnerable to artillery and even fire. One such fort was [Fort Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Fort_Washington) during the American Revolution, which was captured at odds of 8 to 3 in less than a day. After taking heavy casualties in the approach over rough ground, the British breached the walls on two sides, "overrunning" the American positions.

Comment: I could counter with Caesar's ***successful*** defence of his palisade siege-works at Alesia while outnumbered more than 5 to 1. Further, it is questionable if Santa Ana could have made Brigadier in *le Grande Armee*, never mind his delusion of being the *Napoleon of the Western Hemisphere*.

Comment: Alesia was almost two millenia before the Alamo, and the Gauls did not have cannons, mortars or other "fire" weapons. Also, Alesia was considered a high point in siegecraft not exceeded for a long time. And sources dispute the more than 5 to 1 ratio; some say it was more like 3 or 4 to 1.

Comment: The Alamo was hardly a good defensive position and some of the walls fell rather early into the battle.  It was more a total lack of experience on the Mexican side that made the defense even possible.  Having been to the Alamo many times, it is really not a fort by any stretch of the imagination, more like a church that occupied an advantageous position.

Comment: @TomAu: Cannons are irrelevant as, due to the arrival of his mistress, Santa Ana declined to wait 48 hours more for his two 12 pounder cannons to arrive.

Answer (score -1):

This is a history what if question. Likewise I can counter that reinforced concrete with +15 cm artillery and machine guns trumps both adobe and palisade fortresses.

One builds a fortress with what is on hand. In dryer areas that can be adobe, in more wooded areas probably palisades. One isn't necessarily better than the other. They are what is available. Not only that, it's the men defending that do the job. not to mention their commander. The fortress is there to assist them.